# CORS issue with port

Tags: c#, cors

This is in C#:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowMyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(new string[] { "https://*.mySite.com", "https://localhost:*" })
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
        }));
```

And it works for my live site. But when I try to access it from https://localhost:44302/ it doesn't work. What am I missing? I would like fr the port to be generic, not a specific number.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use CORS to enable a host on any port. You need to explicitly add an entry for each port.

```
builder.WithOrigins(new string[] { "https://*.mySite.com", "https://localhost:44302" })
```